# Rebind do notation with typeclass-free monad

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, do-notation

It is possible to rebind the (>>=) and return for a monad using explicit dictionary passing like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

module Lib where

import Prelude hiding ((>>=), return)

data MonadDict m = MonadDict {
  bind :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b ,
  ret :: forall a. a -> m a }

(>>=) :: (MonadDict m -> m a) -> (a -> (MonadDict m -> m b)) -> (MonadDict m -> m b)
return :: a -> (MonadDict m -> m a)

monadDictIO :: MonadDict IO

usage = let
  monadicCode = do
    ln <- const getLine 
    const . putStrLn $ ln
  in monadicCode monadDictIO
```

Is there a better way, how to represent the monad so one can avoid ignoring the `MonadDict` monad instance argument (using `const`) in every usage of the monadic action?

Comment: Surely you would want something more like `(>>=) :: MonadDict m -> m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, or what do you plan to do if you get three different dictionaries?

Comment: @DanielWagner I use it only once see the `usage` part where I pass the dictionary at the very end

Comment: Usually simple invariants like "I only pass one" are good things to ask the type-checker to check for you. The type I proposed is one way to ask it to do so.

Comment: @DanielWagner How would you pass multiple `MonadDict m`s to `>>=`; only one is exposed, the final `MonadDict m` argument; as long as `>>=` passes the argument to that reader to the other two readers the same dictionary will be used for all 3. `(>>=)`'s type is the same as preludes `(>>=)` for `ReaderT (MonadDict m) m`, but has a different implementation.

Comment: @Cirdec Ah, you're right: I had completely misread the type signature!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Lib where
import Prelude hiding(return, fail, (>>=), (>>))

data MonadDict m = MonadDict
    { (>>=)  :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    , (>>)   :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
    , return :: forall a. a -> m a
    , fail   :: forall a. String -> m a
    }

monadDictIO :: MonadDict IO
monadDictIO = ...

foo :: MonadDict m -> String -> m ()
foo = ...

usage = let
    monadicCode m@MonadDict{..} = do
        ln <- getLine
        putStrLn ln
        foo m ln
    in monadicCode monadDictIO
```

Comment: Interesting. Turns out this even works with `-XRecordWildCards`: if you call the `bind` fields `>>=` and `>>` respectively, you can just use `monadicCode MonadDict{..} = do ...`. Whether any of this is a good idea I'm less than certain, but all this is definitely intriguing.

Answer (score 1):

The short and incorrect answer is drop the `MonadDict m` argument from the return type of the second argument to `(>>=)`:

```
(>>=) :: (MonadDict m -> m a) -> (a -> m b) -> (MonadDict m -> m b)
```

But that doesn't really solve all of your syntax problems. If someone has an existing arrow with the type `Monad m => a -> m b`, with explicit dictionary passing it'll have the type `a -> (MonadDict m -> m b)`, and won't be usable as the second argument to `(>>=)`. If there were a function `drop :: (MonadDict m -> m b) -> m b` to make it compatible with the second argument then there'd be no reason to pass `MonadDict`s around.

---

You're reinventing the [`ReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:ReaderT) transformer to read a `MonadDict m`.

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
```

Every time you're using `const` it's the equivalent of `lift` ing an `m a` into `ReaderT (MonadDict m) m a`. Your example wouldn't look so unfamiliar if you wrote it with `lift` instead of `const`.

```
usage = let
  monadicCode = do
    ln <- lift getLine 
    lift . putStrLn $ ln
  in monadicCode monadDictIO
```

Here's a complete example using `ReaderT`; it'd probably be better to make a new type for `ReaderT (MonadDict m) m` and a different name for `lift`. The implementation of `(>>=)` and `return` is identical to `ReaderT`s, except it uses the `bind` or `ret` from the `MonadDict`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}

module Lib
    ( usage
    ) where

import Prelude hiding ((>>=), return)
import qualified Prelude as P ((>>=), return)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

data MonadDict m = MonadDict {
  bind :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b ,
  ret :: forall a. a -> m a }

type ReadM m a = ReaderT (MonadDict m) m a

(>>=) :: ReadM m a -> (a -> ReadM m b) -> ReadM m b
m >>= k = ReaderT $ \d@MonadDict { bind = bind } -> bind (runReaderT m d) (\a -> runReaderT (k a) d)

return :: a -> ReadM m a
return a = ReaderT $ \d@MonadDict { ret = ret } -> ret a

lift :: m a -> ReadM m a
lift m = ReaderT $ \_ -> m

monadDict :: Monad m => MonadDict m
monadDict = MonadDict {
  bind = (P.>>=),
  ret  = P.return
}

example1 :: String -> ReadM IO ()
example1 a = do
    lift . putStrLn $ a
    lift . putStrLn $ a

example2 :: ReadM IO ()
example2 = do
    example1 "Hello"
    ln <- lift getLine 
    lift . putStrLn $ ln

usage :: IO ()
usage = runReaderT example2 monadDict
```

If you give it its own type you can equip it with a `Monad` instance independently of the underlying `m`, and dispense with `RebindableSyntax`.

```
newtype ReadMD m a = ReadMD {runReadMD :: MonadDict m -> m a}

instance Functor (ReadMD f) where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative (ReadMD f) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (ReadMD m) where
    m >>= k = ReadMD $ \d@MonadDict { bind = bind } -> bind (runReadMD m d) (\a -> runReadMD (k a) d)
    return a = ReadMD $ \d@MonadDict { ret = ret } -> ret a
```